# Map between Tangent Manifolds Well-Defined?

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, differential-topology

Let $f: \mathcal{M} \to \mathcal{N}$ be a $\mathscr{C}^{r+1}$ map. We define a map $\mathscr{T}f: \mathscr{T}\mathcal{M} \to \mathscr{T}\mathcal{N}$ as follows:
A local representation of the map $\mathscr{T}f$ in the charts on $\mathscr{T}\mathcal{M}$ and $\mathscr{T}\mathcal{N}$ is simply the derivative of the local representation of $f$ in the charts $\{\psi_i,U_i\}_{i \in \Lambda_1}$ and $\{\theta_i, V_i\}_{i \in \Lambda_2}$ on $\mathcal{M}$ and $\mathcal{N}$, respectively. We have the requirement that $f(U_i) \subset V_i$. Thus we have a $\mathscr{C}^r$ map 
$$ (\mathscr{T}f)_{ij}: \mathscr{T}U_i \to \mathscr{T}V_i$$
$$ [x,i,a] \mapsto [f(x),j,\partial(\theta_jf\psi^{-1}_i)(\psi_i(x))a] $$
Since this is independent of $i,j$, there is a well-defined map $\mathscr{T}f: \mathscr{T}\mathcal{M} \to \mathscr{T}\mathcal{N}$, so that if $f(x) = y$, $\mathscr{T}_xf: \mathscr{T}_x\mathcal{M} \to \mathscr{T}_y\mathcal{N}$.

Now my two questions are, why must we require that $f(U_i) \subset V_j$ for our open coverings? Also, why is the map $(\mathscr{T}f)_{ij}$ independent of $i,j$? I'm told that this is an application of the chain rule, but I don't quite see it.

Comment: Notation is little misleading. You are taking $y$ as a vector of tangent space at a point $x$ and also say that $y=f(x).$ Can you specify a definition of tangent space you are working with? Does $y$ in $[x,i,y]$ depends on chart $\psi_i.$ ?

Comment: @FallenApart My apologies, I fixed the notation. The tangent space is defined as the set of all tangent vectors $[x,i,z] \in \mathcal{M} \times \Lambda \times \mathbb{R}^n$, under the usual equivalence relation.

Comment: If usual equivalence relation means that is $[x_1,i_1,a_1]\sim [x_2,i_2,a_2],$ if $x_1=x_2$ and $\partial(\psi_{i_2}\circ\psi_{i_1}^{-1})a_1=a_2,$ then $a$ depends on chart.

Comment: @FallenApart Yes indeed, forgot to put that in my comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer to the first one is technical. If we would take $U_i$ too big, then the map defined as it has been done
$$(\mathscr{T}f)_{ij}: \mathscr{T}U_i \to \mathscr{T}V_j$$
$$[x,i,a] \mapsto [f(x),j,\partial(\theta_jf\psi^{-1}_i)(\psi_i(x))a],$$

wouldn't have much sense, because for $x\in U_i\setminus f^{-1}(V_j)$ point $y=f(x)$ wouldn't lie in $V_j.$ However if our covering $\{U_i\}$ would be arbitrary, then by the fact that $f$ is continuous we could find a new one which would suffice. Just take covering $\{U_i\cap f^{-1}(V_j)\}$ running for all $i,j.$

To the second one fix $x\in U_{i_1}\cap U_{i_2}$ and recall that the $[x,i_1,a_1]=[x,i_2,a_2]$ if $\partial(\psi_{i_2}\circ\psi_{i_1}^{-1})(\psi_{i_1}(x))a_1=a_2.$ Hence on the one hand
$$[x,i_1,a_1] \mapsto [f(x),j,\partial(\theta_jf\psi^{-1}_{i_1})(\psi_{i_1}(x))a_1]$$ and on the other hand
$$[x,i_2,a_2] \mapsto [f(x),j,\partial(\theta_jf\psi^{-1}_{i_2})(\psi_{i_2}(x))a_2].$$
By the mentioned fact we have that  $\partial(\psi_{i_2}\circ\psi_{i_1}^{-1})(\psi_{i_1}(x))a_1=a_2.$
Plug it in the second, use chain rule and you have the first one. Similar trick with $j.$

Comment: Could you explicitly show the use of the chain rule? I'll be happy to accept this answer if so.

Comment: Are you referring to the expression $$[f(x),j,\partial(\theta_jf\psi^{-1}_{i_2})(\psi_{i_2}(x))\partial(\psi_{i_2} \circ \psi^{-1}_{i_1})a_1]$$?

Comment: In this notation it would be something like this:
Let $U$ be open subset of $R^n,$ $V$ open subset fo $R^m$ an let $F:U\rightarrow R^m$ and $G:V\rightarrow R^p$ be differentiable and let $x\in U$ and $F(x)\in V$. Then for any vector $a\in R^n$
$$\partial (G\circ F)(x)a=\partial G(F(x))\circ \partial F(x)a.$$ If you place $G:=\theta_j f \psi_{i_2}^{-1}, F:=\psi_{i_2}\psi_{i_1},x:=\psi_{i_1},a:=a_1$ you get the result.

Comment: this I understand, but could you explicitly show it for the expression in my comment? I'm not seeing what would be $G$ and $F$ in the expression, nor how this gives the first one.

Comment: I forget to set $\partial(\psi_{i_2}\circ\psi_{i_1}^{-1})a_1=a_2$ at a point. It should be $\partial(\psi_{i_2}\circ\psi_{i_1}^{-1})(\psi_{i_1}(x))a_1=a_2.$

Comment: Bad again. It should be 
$$G:=\theta_j f \psi_{i_2}^{-1}, F:=\psi_{i_2}\psi_{i_1}^{-1},x:=\psi_{i_1}(x),a:=a_1.$$

Comment: So this would give us $(\theta_j f \psi^{-1}_{i_2}\psi_{i_2} \psi^{-1}_{i_1})(\psi_{i_1}(x))a_1 = (\theta_j f \psi^{-1}_{i_1})(\psi_{i_1}(x))a_1 $? You wrote the chain rule in terms of composition of function rather than product of the functions, by the way...

Comment: Yes. But it is just shortcut for composition. There is no algebraic products in here.

Comment: Isn't the $a_1$ being multiplied algebraically? and therefore the $\partial = a_1$ being multiplied algebraically? It doesn't seem to make sense as composition.

Comment: your chain rule should be $\partial (G \circ F)(x)a = \partial G(F(x))\partial F(x)a$?

Comment: It depends what you are mean by $\partial.$ It could be thought as a composition of linear transformation from $R^n$ to $R^m$ and from $R^m$ to $R^p$ or as a product of matrices. If you are thinking in the matrix multiplication. Then in fact it is an algebraic product. You're right.